# RTMP With Node.js Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to set up a Google cloud function via Node.js that receives an RTMP live video stream and saves it all as it comes in piece by piece, preferably to the same file. Looked around and around and unable to find anything here or elsewhere that might help me set up. All the advice on here is basically to set up a Nginx server somewhere else with something else...

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to implement something like that on Cloud Functions.  It doesn't support any form of streaming.  The incoming and outgoing payloads are limited to 10MB each, as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).